# git hook not working with input stream

Tags: git, bash, shell, githooks

I have a git pre-push hook which calls a shell script called pre-push.sh like so

```
#!/bin/bash

#Fail if one script fails and print all info to console
set -ex

#Font variables
underline=`tput smul`
nounderline=`tput rmul`

#Run grunt
grunt;

#Make sure there is only one commit being pushed
printf "\n${underline}Validating Number of Commits${nounderline}\n";
src/scripts/hooks/pre-push/countCommits.sh;
```

Count commits is as such

```
#!/bin/bash


confirm () {
    # call with a prompt string or use a default
    read -r -p "${1:-Are you sure? [y/N]} " response
    case $response in
        [yY][eE][sS]|[yY]) 
            true
            ;;
        *)
            false
            ;;
    esac
}
#This script counts the number of commits being pushed and fails if it is greater than 1 commit being pushed
countCommits(){
    NUMBER_OF_COMMITS=`git rev-list @{u}.. | wc -l`
    if [ "$NUMBER_OF_COMMITS" -gt "1" ]; then
        return 1
        #exit 1
     else
        return 0
    fi

}


if countCommits; then
    printf "\e[0;32mDone, without errors.\e[0m"
else
    printf "$NUMBER_OF_COMMITS commits were pushed. We recommend pushing only 1 commit."
    if confirm "$NUMBER_OF_COMMITS commits were found. We recommend pushing only 1 commit. Do you wish to continue? [y/N]"; then
        :
    else
        printf "Please squash your commits by running \e[1;34m'git rebase -i'\e[0m\n"
        exit 1
    fi
fi
```

when calling pre-push.sh directly it works correctly i.e. waits for the user to say 'y' or 'n' if they have more then 1 commit. However when I use it as a pre-push hook it doesn't wait for the user prompt and continues down the no path

when calling pre-push.sh directly

```
+ src/scripts/hooks/pre-push/countCommits.sh
       5 commits were pushed. We recommend pushing only 1 commit.       5 commits were found. We recommend pushing only 1 commit. Do you wish to continue? [y/N] n
Please squash your commits by running 'git rebase -i'
```

when doing a git push

```
+ src/countCommits.sh
       5 commits were pushed. We recommend pushing only 1 commit.Please squash your commits by running 'git rebase -i'
error: failed to push some refs
```

how do i get the git hook to allow input from the user?

Answer (score 0):

From `man githooks

```
   Information about what is to be pushed is provided on the hook's standard input with lines of the form:

       <local ref> SP <local sha1> SP <remote ref> SP <remote sha1> LF
```

So the script isn't waiting for your manual input, it's just using the first line, which certainly does not match your pattern.

Instead of prompting for whether to continue, you should tell the user that if they really want to push, they should re-run the command with the `--no-verify` argument.

Comment: ok is there a way to use that flag to ignore that one check? within pre-push.sh i have some other checks i would like to keep?